# Objects value differs from what is assigned in method

Tags: python, oop, scope

I define a Point class with a method for rotating around another point:

```
def Rotate(self, origin, degrees):
    d = math.radians(degrees)
    O = origin
    sin = math.sin(d)
    cos = math.cos(d)
    print ("original "+self.ToString())
    self.x += -O.x
    self.y += -O.y
    print ("-origin "+self.ToString())
    WX = self.x * cos -self.y * sin
    WY = self.x * sin +self.y * cos
    self = Point(WX,WY)
    print ("-origin, after transform "+self.ToString())
    self.x += O.x
    self.y += O.y
    print ("End of method "+self.ToString())
```

I then test the method like so:

```
test = [Point(100,100),Point(110,110)]
test[0].Rotate(test[1],10)
print ("outside of method" + test[0].ToString())
```

The output of the print command show that the desired value is assigned at the end of the method, but afterwards is changed.

Why does this happen?

print output:

```
original 100 100
-origin -10 -10
-origin, after transform -8.111595753452777 -11.584559306791382
End of method 101.88840424654722 98.41544069320862
outside of method-10 -10
```

Comment: You assign `self = Point(WX,WY)`. whereas self is a *local* variable.

Comment: I'd recommend you review [the data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) - `ToString` makes it seem like you're writing Java (which [Python is not](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html)). Could you give a [mcve] with a working class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function you write:

```
self = Point(WX,WY)
```

This however has **no effect** outside of the method: now you have **modified the *local* variable `self`**. You cannot reassign `self` in such a way. After you have changed the *local* variable `self`, your `self.x` will of course point to the new `x` attribute of the new `Point(..)`, but you will not have *altered* the object on which you call that method.

What you can do however is **assign to the fields**:

```
self.x, self.y = WX, WY
```

That being said, you can make things more compact:

```
def rotate(self, origin, degrees):
    d = math.radians(degrees)
    sin = math.sin(d)
    cos = math.cos(d)
    dx = self.x - origin.x
    dy = self.y - origin.y
    wx = dx * cos - dy * sin + origin.x
    wy = dx * sin + dy * cos + origin.y
    self.x = wx
    self.y = wy
```